# Concatenating an immediate if into a var

Tags: javascript

This for whatever reason doesn't seem to be working. I would like to concatenate a bunch of these types of strings into 1 long string:

```
var sql = 'SELECT FROM TBL_IMTS WHERE\n'+
          (firstname == 0)?"empty":"not empty"\n'
```

How do I get the strings to join properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var sql = 'SELECT FROM TBL_IMTS WHERE\n';
sql += (firstname == 0)?"empty":"not empty";
sql += '\n';
```

Might be easier to read.

Answer (score 2):

You have an unexpected \ character.

```
var sql = "SELECT FROM TBL_IMTS WHERE\n" + (!firstname ? "empty" : "not empty") + "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

try the following

```
var sql = 'SELECT FROM TBL_IMTS WHERE\n' + ((firstname == 0)?'empty':'not empty') + '\n;
```

you were messing something up with the ' and " thingys :)